# Reverse engineer a Cube to build a Relational database using SSAS 2008

Tags: reverse-engineering, ssas

I have a requirement where in i have a cube which was built in AS 2000 and all i have is just the backup of the analysis service database .

I have to build a relational database with Facts and Dimensions,restore the database in 2008 R2 and then build a new cube on SSAS 2008 based on the datawarehouse that i have .

I have been writing mdx queries with cross joins to get the dimension data as well as the measure but this procedure is costing me a lot of memory ( i currently have 4 GB memory and 14 dimensions) . When i try to do a cross join , the query was able to give me the results for maximum of 7 dimensions and anything more that ended in the application getting frozen ( hanged) and i had to kill the process manually.

Could anyone provide me a feasible and an efficient solution to this

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Savio

Answer (score 0):

well, its not possible to create the DW that "originated" a cube based on the actual cube because there are several DW structures that can result in a cube.

What you can do is restore your cube backup to a AS 2000 instance, migrate it to SSAS 2008 and then create a new project in BIDS, choose the option "Import Analysis Service 2008 Database" and point to the instance that you just created. BIDS will read the structure of the deployed cube and create you a SSAS project